# Effective Algorithms for selecting the top k ( in percent) items from a datastream:

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I have to repeatedly sort an array containing 300 random elements. But i have to do a special kind of sort: I need the 5% smallest values from an subset of the array, then some value is calculated and the subset is increased. Now the value is calculated again and the subset also increased. And so on until the subset contains the whole array.

The subset starts with the first 10 elements and is increased by 10 elements after each step.
i.e. :

subset-size              k=ceil(5%*subset)
 10                            1          (so just the smallest element)
20                            1           (so also just the smallest)
 
30                            2           (smallest and second smallest)

...

The calculated value is basically a sum of all elements smaller than k and the specially weighted k smallest element.
In code:

```
k = ceil(0.05 * subset) -1; // -1 because array index starts with 0...  
temp = 0.0; 
for( int i=0  i<k; i++)
    temp += smallestElements[i];
temp += b *  smallestElements[i];
```

I have implemented myself a selection sort based algorithm (code at the end of this post). I use MAX(k) pointers to keep track of the k smallest elements. Therefore I unnecessarily sort all elements smaller than k :/ 
Furthermore I know selection sort is bad for performance, which is unfortunately crucial in my case.

I tried figuring out a way how I could use some quick- or heapsort based algorithm. I know that quickselect or heapselect are perfect for finding the k smallest elements if k and the subset is fixed.
But because my subset is more like an input stream of data I think that quicksort based algorithm drop out. 
I know that heapselect would be perfect for a data stream if k is fixed. But I don't manage it to adjust heapselect for dynamic k's without big performance drops, so that it is less effective than my  selection-sort based version :( Can anyone help me to modify heap-select for dynamic k's?

If there is no better algorithm, you maybe find a different/faster approach for my selection sort implementation. Here is a minimal example of my implementation, the calculated variable isn't used in this example, so don't worry about it. (In my real programm i have just some loops unrolled manually for better performance)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 300
#define STEP_SIZE 10

float sortStream( float*  array, float**  pointerToSmallest, int k_max){    
    int  i,j,k,last = k_max-1;
    float temp=0.0;

// init first two pointers  
    if( array[0] < array[1] ){  
        pointerToSmallest[0] = &array[0];
        pointerToSmallest[1] = &array[1];
    }else{
        pointerToSmallest[0] = &array[1];
        pointerToSmallest[1] = &array[0];
    }
// Init remaining pointers until i= k_max
    for(i=2; i< k_max;++i){
        if( *pointerToSmallest[i-1] < array[i] ){   
            pointerToSmallest[i] = &array[i];
        }else{  
            pointerToSmallest[i] = pointerToSmallest[i-1];
            for(j=0; j<i-1 && *pointerToSmallest[i-2-j] > array[i];++j)
                pointerToSmallest[i-1-j] = pointerToSmallest[i-2-j];            
            pointerToSmallest[i-1-j]=&array[i];         
        }   
        if((i+1)%STEP_SIZE==0){
            k = ceil(0.05 * i)-1;       
            for(j=0; j<k; j++)
                temp += *pointerToSmallest[j];
            temp += 2 * (*pointerToSmallest[k]);
        }
    }
// Selection sort remaining elements    
    for( ; i< ARRAY_SIZE; ++i){     
        if( *pointerToSmallest[ last ] > array[i] ) {       
            for(j=0; j != last && *pointerToSmallest[ last-1-j] > array[i];++j)
                pointerToSmallest[last-j] = pointerToSmallest[last-1-j];            
            pointerToSmallest[last-j] = &array[i];      
        }       
        if( (i+1)%STEP_SIZE==0){
            k = ceil(0.05 * i)-1;       
            for(j=0; j<k; j++)
                temp += *pointerToSmallest[j];  
            temp += 2 * (*pointerToSmallest[k]);        
        }
    }   
    return temp;

}

int main(void){
    int     i,k_max = ceil( 0.05 * ARRAY_SIZE );
    float*  array = (float*)malloc ( ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float));
    float** pointerToSmallest = (float**)malloc( k_max * sizeof(float*));
    for( i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            array[i]= rand() / (float)RAND_MAX*100-50;

    // just return a, so that the compiler doens't drop the function call
    float a = sortStream(array,pointerToSmallest, k_max);
    return (int)a;
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: surely a min heap would be more appropriate?

Comment: A stream is by definition an incomplete dataset. You appear to have all your elements in the array at the outset of the algorithm. What makes this a stream?

Comment: yes its not directly a stream, but i have to treat it like one. Also i think, that k% out auf a stream is a more general approach to the problem, so that more people have been confronted with this task and maybe someone else can use the answers.

Answer (score 1):

By using two heap for storing all items from stream, you can:

1. find top p% elements in O(1)
2. update data structure (two heaps) in O(log N)

assume, now we have N elements, k = p% *N,

1. min heap (LargerPartHeap) for storing top k items
2. max heap (SmallerPartHeap) for storing the other (N - k) items.

all items in SmallerPartHeap is less or equal to min items of LargerPartHeap (top item @ LargerPartHeap).

1. for query "what is top p% elements?", simply return LargerPartHeap
2. for update "new element x from stream",

   2.a check new k' = (N + 1) * p%, if k' = k + 1, move top of SmallerPartHeap to LargerPartHeap. - O(logN)

   2.b if x is larger than top element (min element) of LargerPartHeap, insert x to LargerPartHeap, and move top of LargerPartHeap to SmallerPartHeap; otherwise, insert x to SmallerPartHeap - O(logN)

Answer (score 0):

I believe heap sort is far too complicated for this particular problem, even though that or other priority queue algorithms are well suited to get N minimum or maximum items from a stream.

The first notice is the constraint 0.05 * 300 = 15. That is the maximum amount of data, that has to be sorted at any moment. Also during each iteration one has add 10 elements. The overall operation *in-place* could be:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
 {
      if (i != 1)
         qsort(input + i*10, 10, sizeof(input[0]), cmpfunc);
      else
         qsort(input, 20, sizeof(input[0]), cmpfunc);

      if (i > 1)
        merge_sort15(input, 15, input + i*10, 10, cmpfunc);
 }
```

When i==1, one could also merge sort input and input+10 to produce completely sorted array of 20 inplace, since that has lower complexity than the generic `sort`. Here the "optimizing" is also on minimizing the primitives of the algorithm.

Merge_sort15 would only consider the first 15 elements of the first array and the first 10 elements of the next one.

**EDIT** The parameters of the problem will have a considerable effect in choosing the right algorithm; here selecting 'sort 10 items' as basic unit will allow one half of the problem to be parallelized, namely sorting 30 individual blocks of 10 items each -- a problem which can be efficiently solved with fixed pipeline algorithm using sorting networks. With different parametrization such an approach may not be feasible.